# JavaScript не работает цикл FOR

Tags: ajax, for

Всем Добрый день!
Помогите разобратся:

Ядея в том чтобы через цикл отправлять запросы AJAX и в зависимоти от значения post_id, менял в определённом теге инфу.

Проблема в том что он менят только у одного post_id и всё.

Спасибо заранее!

```
function post_content(){
        var post_id = document.getElementsByClassName("post_ids");
        var j = "";
        alert(post_id.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < post_id.length; i++){ 

            j = post_id[i].innerText.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
            if(j.length>0){
            var tag_id = document.getElementById(j);

            $.ajax({
               url: "cart/post_content.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: ({post_set:"set",post_id : j}),
               success: function(data){

                        tag_id.innerHTML = data;

                        var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event');
                        var d= document.getElementById('d');
                        d.innerHTML =  articles[articles.length-1].outerHTML.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
                    }
            });
            }else j = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax в отдельную функцию.

```
function post_content(){
    var post_id = document.getElementsByClassName("post_ids"),
        j = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < post_id.length; i++){ 
        j = post_id[i].innerText.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
        if(j.length>0){     
            getAjaxPost(j);
        }else{
            j = "";
        }
    }
}

function getAjaxPost(id) {
    var tag_id = document.getElementById(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "cart/post_content.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({post_set:"set",post_id : id}),
        success: function(data){
            tag_id.innerHTML = data;
            var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event'),
                d= document.getElementById('d');
            d.innerHTML =  articles[articles.length-1].outerHTML.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Андрей ProjectSoft

Крассавчик!

Comment: Андрей - у меня есть ещё один вопрос:

Comment: твоё решение помогло очень сильно
Но появилась 2-я проблемма
Он выгружает информацию но ставит её не правильно (хаотично)


Как доделать функцию чтобы он искал нужный результат не во всём документе а именно в переменной data которую он получил
...................................................................................Пример:
         


 var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event')

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` может быть вызван в контексте DOM-элемента. Т. е. `tag_id.getElementsByClassName('cell tracking-result-header-event')`